# How do I intercept web browser traffic in python?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

I want to intercept all destinations, so I can reroute them, kind of like a virtual lan. How would I intercept and find the hostname of a destination packet?

I've searched the web but I haven't found anything. I would like it to be like a device driver, it starts and waits for web browsers to request a specific IP or domain name, and reroute it to a different IP or domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You do that using a (local) "proxy" process.  There are several solutions to set up such a "web proxy".  You can even write one using a few lines of python capturing HTTP-traffic.

However, since most HTTPS web traffic is nowadays protected by SSL/TLS, you probably can't inspect the *plain text* details of the internet traffic without resorting to specific techniques.

Comment: How would I do sometging like this, though? I can't find anything on local proxies.

Comment: On which OS do you want to run the web browser?

Comment: I want to run it on windows.